# How can I move data(managedobject) from one tableview to another tableview when I used 2 tableviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

### Situation

Two tableviews (I used coredata)

If there are two tableviews, is it possible to move data between them?

Like "awesome note application" (moving memo to folder.....)

For example, In first tableview I input some data like `A, B, C, D, E, F`

Of these, I want to move `DATA(C, D, E, F)` to second tableview and I wonder how only `A,B` do that to show in first tableview

Note that : Data is not fixed...

```
A, B, C, D, E, F ------> Tableview 1 (if I input change method)

C, D, E, F ------> Tableview 1 &&& A, B -------> Tableview 2
```

### View structure

```
main view(UIView) ------> tableview 1.

                  ------> tableview 2.
```

Comment: How about just to add one more (e.g. "BOOL belongsToTable1") parameter to your core data object model? So that you can understand, which tableView this taken object belongs to, and accordingly it's easy to draw both tableViews properly.

Comment: Thanks. I used coredatarecipe example.(apple sample code). But really I don't know how to connect new model and existing model. Can you advise for me about them?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions that people are suggesting are not great.

The problem with adding a `BOOL` is that it is not scalable and it is treating the symptom and not the problem.

The problem is that you want something that looks like a parent/child relationship.

Using your memo/folder example you would need something like this:

```
folder <-->> memos
```

Answer (score 0):

@second comment under the question:

You shouldn't create something new, just edit the old datamodel. Use the graph scheme for this purpose:

1. click on your objectmodel, this will open the graph for you
2. click on the class you're interested in (e.g. "Entity")
3. Add the property (e.g. 'belongsToTable1') and set its type up
4. Edit (add your new property to the sources) or generate (you can do it manually or automatically generate with the help of xcode) new sources (don't forget to delete the old ones in this case) for your "Entity" class.
5. Note that at this step (after changing your datamodel graph) your database does NOT correspond to the datamodel anymore, so if you launch your program now, it will crash. Therefore you have to find the data of your project (it should be ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/your.SDK.version/codeOfYourApp) and remove your database file.
6. Launch your project as before, and if it doesn't fall, you've done correctly your changes. From now on in your project just use your updated Entity class.

Don't forget, that BOOL in core data is represented with type NSNumber. So when you read the property from the object, you should use something like:

```
if ([objectOfEntityClass.yourBoolParameter boolValue]) {}
```

And when you set it, you should use smth like

```
objectOfEntityClass.yourBoolParameter = [NSNumber numberWithBool:yourBoolValue];
```

Also if the answers are useful for you (e.g. my answer) don't forget to mark it as an answer to your question or at least vote it up ;)

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Oh..now I read your comment. Thanks a lot. Good luck friendly guys.